# How to read and play an audio file for my OS?

Tags: c, audio, operating-system, ports, interrupt

I am building a small OS. For that i wanted to play audio. I can use ports,interrupts. I have **no restrictions as i am building an OS** itself.

So **how can i play an audio file using a C program. Please remember that I cannot and don't want to use any ready made library or so.**

Comment: no. I want to know how its done. And how i can do it. I have no idea about it. So i want the info. Not actual implementation. Please get me wrong.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable question to me... he's asking how to get started programming the hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're building your own OS, you also need to care about the physical details of your audio hardware.

Differences in hardware is why operating systems introduced the concept of the device driver.

If your audio hardware is sound blaster compatible, have a look here:

http://www.phatcode.net/res/243/files/sbhwpg.pdf

There's an archive of lots of hardware-near audio code here (various hardware platforms):

http://www.dcee.net/Files/Programm/Sound/

Here's a chapter on programming sound devices:

http://www.oreilly.de/catalog/multilinux/excerpt/ch14-01.htm

Comment: Thank you sir. I got lot of details from there. :)

Comment: Updated with a few other references.

Comment: I think with all that may be i can do what i wanted to do. Thank you once again sir.